# Move Git repositories between team projects

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, version-control

I want to move a project with all it's history and commits including any feature branches but I've been unsuccessful.

Unfortunately the [5 'easy' steps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/move-git-repos-between-team-projects) detailed on visualstudio articles do not clearly state when one needs to use the source or the target clone url or which folder I should be in.

I did the following, it just cloned my files but didn't clone the feature branches even though the message say it has created it.

This is where my current project lives oldTeam > myProject. I want to move that to my new team; newTeam > myProject

I've created a new repo for myProject under newTeam and copied the clone URL

In Git CMD

c:\webapps\oldTeam\myProject> git clone --mirror [cloned URL from above step]

```
Cloning into bare repository 'myproject.git'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

c:\webapps\oldTeam\myProject> git push --mirror [cloned URL from above step]

```
Counting objects: 446, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (364/364), done.
Writing objects: 100% (446/446), 3.81 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 446 (delta 79), reused 416 (delta 64)
remote: Analyzing objects... (446/446) (478 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (435 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (43 ms)
To [cloned URL from above step]
 * [new branch]      develop -> develop
 * [new branch]      master -> master
 * [new branch]      origin/HEAD -> origin/HEAD
 * [new branch]      origin/develop -> origin/develop
 * [new branch]      origin/feature/XYZ -> origin/feature/XYZ
 * [new branch]      origin/master -> origin/master
```

When I look at my new repository, I can see my files, master and development branch but not my feature branches. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find in the push output message that `develop` and `master` branch have not `origin/` in front, that means your local repo only have `develop` and `master` branch locally.

So you need to checkout the feature branch locally and then push to another empty trpo. Detail steps as below:

```
git checkout feature/XYZ
git push --mirror [cloned URL from above step]
```

Since the new repo is not empty anymore, you can push feature/XYZ to the new repo by another way:

```
git remote add new [cloned URL from above step]
git push new feature/XYZ
```

Comment: I gave up trying to do this as it did not work, I checked out the branch and ran the above command but it didn't create it. I ended up creating everything from scratch.

Comment: You can't to use the commands above since the repo is not empty any more, you need to use the commands with empty repo. And make sure all the branches are checkout locally.

Comment: I did what you described with another project of mine but using a empty project and it worked, thank you.